# Error setting up Webmachine

Tags: erlang, webmachine

I'm on OS X 10.10.1 and I have Erlang installed. Namely:

`Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]`

I would like to follow one of the many webmachine introductory [tutorials](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Web_Development_with_Webmachine_for_Erlang), and create a new project - unfortunately I always get stuck. Here's my process:

1. `$ git clone https://github.com/basho/webmachine.git`
2. `$ ./webmachine/scripts/new_webmachine.sh testproject`

The second command fails with:

`==> priv (create)
ERROR: Template wmskel not found.
ERROR: create failed while processing /Users/wasabii/webmachine/priv: rebar_abort`

I have not been able to get any further than the above error message, displayed on both Ubuntu 14 and OS X. In the former case, it was a fresh setup, that only performed a `sudo apt-get git/erlang` before attempting to run the shell script.

Is there something I'm missing? I don't quite understand the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears you've run into a problem caused by an update to the `rebar` executable in the top-level directory of the `webmachine` repository. If you check out commit a85499e instead, everything should work as you'd expect:

```
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
$ ./scripts/new_webmachine.sh testproject /tmp
==> priv (create)
ERROR: Template wmskel not found.
ERROR: create failed while processing /usr/local/src/webmachine/priv: rebar_abort
$ git checkout a85499e
Note: checking out 'a85499e'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at a85499e... Merge pull request #210 from basho/feature/log-request-times
$ ./scripts/new_webmachine.sh testproject /tmp
==> priv (create)
Writing /tmp/testproject/README
Writing /tmp/testproject/Makefile
Writing /tmp/testproject/rebar.config
Writing /tmp/testproject/rebar
Writing /tmp/testproject/start.sh
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject.app.src
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject.erl
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject_app.erl
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject_sup.erl
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject_config.erl
Writing /tmp/testproject/src/testproject_resource.erl
```

I've reported this as [an issue in the webmachine github repository](https://github.com/basho/webmachine/issues/229).

Comment: The above solution has solved my problem! Thank you, hopefully the HEAD will have the bug fixed soon.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to fix the problem: https://github.com/basho/webmachine/pull/230 . You could also try applying the simple patch there to your own clone to allow you to use HEAD instead.

Comment: My fix was [merged](https://github.com/basho/webmachine/commit/2e8caa8c97b00af98ab02ebd7d52e749a74d4018) so the webmachine `develop` branch should now no longer have this problem.